# Words made from strokes of a kanji like 女 toくノ一

Tags: kanji, etymology

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunoichi), one theory for the etymology of くノ一 (female ninja) is that it's made up of the [strokes](http://tomoegozen.free.fr/bujinkan-tomoegozen-kunoichi.html) of the kanji 女 (woman).

Other theories include that it means nine and one, talking about the number of [orifices](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8F%E3%83%8E%E4%B8%80) men and women have, and yet another is that the term くノ一 is apocryphal. Finally, [this page](http://villages.likenaruto.com/space.php?uid=69&do=blog&id=284) suggests that くノ一 might be "real", but is just a code word used by ninjas to mean woman, rather than meaning female ninja.

Are there any other words, historical or present, where the characters are made up of strokes of a kanji, along the lines of the 女 etymology theory for くノ一?

Comment: Wow, I've always remembered the stroke order for 女 by thinking of く、の、一 in my head, and I thought it was helpful that くの一 is actually a word, but I had no idea this was a possible origin of 女.

Comment: @atlantiza: I think that you have misunderstood what is stated in the question.  くノ一 cannot be the origin of Chinese character 女 because that would contradict the chronological order.

Comment: +1. This question has maximum trivia value.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "rebus". Unfortunately doing a google for the keywords "Japanese" and "rebus" does not return any results useful to this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ロハ. This word is colloquial and I think mostly extinct now, but it means "free [as in beer]" and derives from the kanji 只, which is one way to write the word ただ, which means (among other things) "free".

Comment: Wow... I was sure there were going to be no other examples because it just seemed too obscure. Nice find! :)

Comment: By googling for pages with くノ一, 女, ロハ, and 只, I came across http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yam3104/20100714 - can someone confirm the page is talking about this phenomenon?

Comment: Nah, most of them are just puzzles. くノ一 and ロハ are genuine words, but I don't think anyone actually says ロロ instead of 回. "いと（糸）し、いと（糸）しと言ふ心→戀（こひ）" is a bit closer to what you're looking for, but again, no-one actually says "いとし、いとしと言ふ心" instead of 恋, it's not a case of new words evolving from kanji, just a one-off puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any other words, historical or present, where the characters are made up of strokes of a kanji, along the lines of the 女 etymology theory for くノ一?

An example from present-day usage is [タヒる](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%92%E3%82%8B) from 死ぬ.

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard the saying 女三人寄れば姦しい (three women together make a terrible racket)?

The kanji for the word 姦【かしま】しい (noisy) is made up of three women...

Comment: Related is the kanji for 嬲る (or even 嫐る)

Comment: And 森 (three kanji for trees) can mean forest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight divergence from what you're asking (a phrase that's a reference to a kanji rather than breaking up a single kanji into strokes), but I think another interesting word is 「川{かわ}の字{じ}」, a word to describe the state where three people are sleeping side by side (typically, where two parents are sleeping with their child between them). I think this word is even less common than ロハ though.

Comment: I get that 川 is a cryptic reference to the arrangement of the people, but what does 字 have to do with sleeping?

Comment: The 字 doesn't have to do with sleeping; 「川の字」 is literally translated as "the character for river." The 字 is specifically pointing out that the people are in the shape of the character itself. I think you're overthinking it :)

Comment: On a similar note, the word for cross is 十字架.

Comment: There's also 大の字, which is if someone is in the "spread eagle" position :)